# Pellet Stove Ventilation

Tags: hvac, fireplace

I have an Englander PDVC pellet stove that came with my house when I bought it in the spring.  Never used it.  Currently its vented through the wall and comes straight through the exterior of the house a couple feet. The existing is getting rust but also leaves some soot on the exterior of the house/  What I want to do is go out about the same length but put an elbow to go up at a 90 about 3-4 feet and put some type of cap that will prevent rain from coming through it.  I am pretty handy but never really worked with HVAC duct work before.  What do I need to do this?

Comment: You should contact your local building department, and find out if they have any requirements.  It sounds to me like it's not up to code, but I don't know where you live, so I can't say for sure. Typically, fuel burning appliances have to vent above the structure they're in, so combustion byproducts are kept away from people.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pellet stoves, but I'm guessing you'll have to use double walled tube. You'll probably also have to have a collar around the pipe where it passes through the wall, to keep combustible material away from the pipe. Don't know how hot the exhaust is from a pellet stove.  If it's anywhere near as hot as a wood stove, improper installation can be a major fire hazard.

Comment: You should follow the manufacturers instructions about venting (pellet stove pipe is NOT HVAC duct, for one thing) and the required sizes for various configurations (ie, you can probably do something like what you want, but you may need to use 4" rather than 3" vent due to the added length and added "effective length" due to elbows. Try hearth.com (not SE, but a good place for combustion appliance advice.) If that stove can take an outside air kit (OAK) but does not have one, adding one is highly advisable.